# Child class of DbContext returns no data

Tags: entity-framework-4, dbcontext

Here's my sub-class of my DbContext:

```
public class JalsoxDbContextCache : JalsoxDbContext, IJalsoxDbContext
{

}
```

Any ideas why it would return no data where as if I use the base class instead it does?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the class is used to create the connection string.

So I changed the derived class to this:

```
public class JalsoxDbContextCache : JalsoxDbContext, IJalsoxDbContext
{
    public JalsoxDbContextCache()
        : base("JalsoxDbContext")
    {
    }
}
```

How strange!